# "Deal or No Deal" console game

Tags: java, object-oriented, game

Can anyone check this code of mine for improvements?  This was coded using Java with OOP concepts.

**`Game` Class**

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Game {

    Player player = new Player();

    Banker banker = new Banker();

    private int a = 0;

    private int b = 6;

    private double myAmount = 0;

    private double offer = 0;

    private int turn = 1;

    private int cases = 26;

    private double amounts[] = { 23, 1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100,
            200, 300, 400, 500, 750, 1000, 5000, 10000, 25000, 50000, 75000,
            100000, 300000, 400000, 500000, 750000, 1000000, 250000, 800 };

    private String models[] = { "Nayer", "Michelle", "Obama", "Rosey", "Miney",
            "Ashley", "Maria", "Ozawa", "Audrey", "Kristen", "Kim",
            "Kardashian", "Kourtney", "Ann", "Macy", "Tori", "Sam", "Monica",
            "Jin", "Koi", "jill", "Usher", "Justin Bieber", "Lindsay Lohan",
            "Hazell", "Buttercup", "Don Amalia", "Kojic!" };

    Briefcase briefcase[] = new Briefcase[27];

    Model lady[] = new Model[27];

    public void setladies() {
        for (int i = 0; i < lady.length; i++) {
            lady[i] = new Model();
            String name = models[i];
            lady[i].setName(name);
        }
    }

    public void Shuffle() {

        Random rgen = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < amounts.length - 1; i++) {
            int Position = rgen.nextInt(amounts.length);
            double temp = amounts[i];
            amounts[i] = amounts[Position];
            amounts[Position] = temp;
        }
    }

    public void casesSetup() {
        Shuffle();
        for (int i = 0; i < briefcase.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
            } else {
            }
            briefcase[i] = new Briefcase();
            double value = amounts[i];
            briefcase[i].setAmount(value);
            briefcase[i].setFace(i);
        }
    }

    public void showCases() {
        for (int a = 0; a < briefcase.length; a++) {
            if (a == 0) {
            } else if (briefcase[a] == null) {
                System.out.print("\t[X]");
            } else {
                System.out.print("\t[" + briefcase[a].getFace() + "]");
            }
            if (a % 5 == 0) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }

        System.out.println();
    }

    public void Welcome() {
        System.out.println("\t~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*");
        System.out.println("\t~*               Welcome !          ~*");
        System.out.println("\t~*~*~*~*~* Hosted by Kyel David ~*~*~*~*~*~*");
        System.out.println("\t~* Please Select from the Following Cases!~*");
        System.out.println("\t~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*");
    }

    public void starGame() {

        boolean gamestatus = true;
        casesSetup();
        Welcome();
        showCases();
        setladies();

        int choice = player.nUser();
        myAmount = briefcase[choice].getAmount();
        briefcase[choice] = null;
        cases--;

        while (gamestatus == true) {
            showCases();
            if (cases == 25 || cases == 19 || cases == 14 || cases == 10
                    || cases == 7) {
                for (a = b; a > 0; a--) {
                    int r = player.Remove(a, briefcase, models);
                    briefcase[r] = null;
                    cases--;
                }
                b--;
                turn++;
                banker.setOffer(turn,briefcase,myAmount);
                offer = banker.getOffer(turn, briefcase, myAmount);
                gamestatus = player.gamestatus();
            } else if (cases == 1) {
                int r = player.Remove(1, briefcase, models);
                briefcase[r] = null;
                gamestatus = false;
            } else {
                int r = player.Remove(1, briefcase, models);
                briefcase[r] = null;
                cases--;
                banker.setOffer(turn,briefcase,myAmount);
                offer = banker.getOffer(turn, briefcase, myAmount);
                gamestatus = player.gamestatus();
            }
        }
        finishgame();
    }

    public void finishgame() {
        if (cases == 1) {
            System.out.println("\tYou Rejected the Offer of Banker");
            System.out
            .printf("\tYour case contains $%.2f and the bankers offer is $%.2f\n",
                    myAmount, offer);
            System.out.printf("\tYou've won your case with an amount of: %.2f",
                    myAmount);
        } else {
            System.out.println("\tYou Accepted the offer of Banker");
            System.out
            .printf("\tYour case contains $%.2f and the bankers offer is $%.2f\n",
                    myAmount, offer);
            System.out.printf("\tYou've won the offer of Banker: $%.2f", offer);
        }
    }
}
```

**`Player` Class**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Player {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Banker banker = new Banker();

    public boolean gamestatus() {
        System.out.print("\tAccept or Reject! [1]Accept [2]reject: ");
        int temp = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        if (temp == 1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public int nUser() {

        boolean isOkay = false;
        int nUser = 0;
        while (isOkay == false) {
            System.out.print("\n\tPlease Select Your Case!: ");
            nUser = input.nextInt();
            if (nUser < 0 || nUser >= 27) {
                System.out.println("\tInvalid input Try again");
            } else {
                isOkay = true;
            }
        }
        return nUser;
    }

    public int Remove(int i, Briefcase c[], String[] m) {

        int nChoice = 0;
        boolean inputisok = false;

        while (inputisok == false) {
            System.out.print("\tPlease remove " + i + " case/s: "); 
            nChoice = input.nextInt();
            if (nChoice < 0 || nChoice >= c.length || c[nChoice] == null) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("\tInvalid Input please Try again\n");
            } else {
                System.out.println("\tI'm " + m[nChoice]
                        + " You just removed case # " + nChoice);
                System.out.println("\t|" + nChoice + "| contains $"
                        + c[nChoice].getAmount() + "\n");
                inputisok = true;
            }

        }
        return nChoice;
    }
}
```

**`Banker` Class**

```
public class Banker {

    private double total = 0;
    private int a = 0;
    private double amount =0;
    double Average = 0;

    public void setOffer(int turn, Briefcase[] cases, double myAmount) {

        for (int i = 0; i < cases.length; i++) {
            if (cases[i] == null) {
            } else {
                total = total + cases[i].getAmount();
                a++;
            }
        }
        Average = myAmount+total / a;
        amount = Average*turn/ 10;
    }

    public double getOffer(int turn, Briefcase[] cases, double myAmount) {
        setOffer(turn, cases, myAmount);
        System.out.printf("\tThe Bankers Offer is: %.2f \n\n", amount);
        return amount;
    }
}
```

**`Model` Class**

```
public class Model {

    private String mName;

    public void setName(String mName) {

        this.mName = mName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

}
```

**`Briefcase` Class**

```
public class Briefcase {

    private double amount;
    private int face;

    public void setAmount(double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public double getAmount() {

        return this.amount;
    }

    public void setFace(int face) {
        this.face = face;
    }

    public int getFace() {
        return face;
    }

}
```

**Main class**

```
public class Play {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game dnd = new Game();
        dnd.starGame();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

There are a few things, I'll expand on this over time. First, always write method and variable names in **lowerCamelCase**. Everything starting with an uppercase letter wil be considered a class or a constant by other programmers.

Then, don't use mechanically getters and setters. E.g. consider

```
public class Model {

    private String mName;

    public void setName(String mName) {

        this.mName = mName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

}
```

Do you ever change the name of a `Model` afterwards? No? Is it okay to have a `Model` without name? No? Then a correct implementation is:

```
public class Model {

    private final String mName;

    public Model(String mName) {
        this.mName = mName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

}
```

You could opt for implementing `toString` instead of `getName`, or even for making the member variable public (because it's final, and `String` is immutable).

**[Some Random Thoughts]**

Try to simplify logical expressions as much as possible:

```
if (temp == 1) {
   return false;
} else {
   return true;
}
```

is the same as simply `return temp != 1;`.

Use API functions where possible. E.g. there is `java.util.Collections.shuffle` for `List`s.

What is with the empty {} in `casesSetup` and `showCases`?

**[Suggestion]**

```
public class Banker {

    private double total = 0;
    private int a = 0;
    private double amount =0;
    double average = 0;

    public void setOffer(int turn, Briefcase[] cases, double myAmount) {

        for (int i = 0; i < cases.length; i++) {
            if (! cases[i].isRemoved()) {
                total += cases[i].getAmount();
                a++;
            }
        }
        average = myAmount + total / a;
        amount = average*turn/ 10;
    }

    public double getOffer(int turn, Briefcase[] cases, double myAmount) {
        setOffer(turn, cases, myAmount);
        System.out.printf("\tThe Bankers Offer is: %.2f \n\n", amount);
        return amount;
    }
}
```

.

```
public class Briefcase {
    private final double amount;
    private final String model;
    private boolean removed = false;
    private String face;

    public Briefcase(double amount, int face, String model) {
        this.face = Integer.toString(face);
        this.amount = amount;
        this.model = model;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return face;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void remove() {
        removed = true;
        face = "X";
    }

    public boolean isRemoved() {
        return removed;
    }
}
```

.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Game {
    private Player player = new Player();
    private Banker banker = new Banker();
    private int a = 0;
    private int b = 6;
    private double myAmount = 0;
    private double offer = 0;
    private int turn = 1;
    private int cases = 26;
    private Briefcase briefcases[];

    public void casesSetup() {
        String[] modelNames = {"Michelle", "Obama", "Rosey", "Miney",
            "Ashley", "Maria", "Ozawa", "Audrey", "Kristen", "Kim",
            "Kardashian", "Kourtney", "Ann", "Macy", "Tori", "Sam", "Monica",
            "Jin", "Koi", "jill", "Usher", "Justin Bieber", "Lindsay Lohan",
            "Hazell", "Buttercup", "Don Amalia", "Kojic!"};

        List<Integer> amounts = Arrays.asList(1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100,
        200, 300, 400, 500, 750, 1000, 5000, 10000, 25000, 50000, 75000,
        100000, 300000, 400000, 500000, 750000, 1000000, 250000, 800);

        Collections.shuffle(amounts);

        briefcases = new Briefcase[amounts.size()];

        for (int i = 0; i < briefcases.length; i++) {
            double value = amounts.get(i);
            briefcases[i] = new Briefcase(value, i + 1, modelNames[i]);
        }
    }

    public void showCases() {
        for (int i = 0; i < briefcases.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("\t[" + briefcases[i] + "]");
            if (i % 5 == 4) {
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void welcomeMessage() {
        System.out.println("\t~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*");
        System.out.println("\t~*               Welcome !          ~*");
        System.out.println("\t~*~*~*~*~* Hosted by Kyel David ~*~*~*~*~*~*");
        System.out.println("\t~* Please Select from the Following Cases!~*");
        System.out.println("\t~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*~*");
    }

    public void startGame() {

        boolean gamestatus = true;
        casesSetup();
        welcomeMessage();
        showCases();

        int choice = player.nUser();
        myAmount = briefcases[choice].getAmount();
        briefcases[choice].remove();
        cases--;

        while (gamestatus == true) {
            showCases();
            if (cases == 25 || cases == 19 || cases == 14 || cases == 10
                    || cases == 7) {
                for (a = b; a > 0; a--) {
                    player.remove(a, briefcases);
                    cases--;
                }
                b--;
                turn++;
                banker.setOffer(turn, briefcases, myAmount);
                offer = banker.getOffer(turn, briefcases, myAmount);
                gamestatus = player.gamestatus();
            } else if (cases == 1) {
                player.remove(1, briefcases);
                gamestatus = false;
            } else {
                player.remove(1, briefcases);
                cases--;
                banker.setOffer(turn, briefcases, myAmount);
                offer = banker.getOffer(turn, briefcases, myAmount);
                gamestatus = player.gamestatus();
            }
        }
        finishgame();
    }

    public void finishgame() {
        if (cases == 1) {
            System.out.println("\tYou Rejected the Offer of Banker");
            System.out.printf("\tYour case contains $%.2f and the bankers offer is $%.2f\n",
                    myAmount, offer);
            System.out.printf("\tYou've won your case with an amount of: %.2f",
                    myAmount);
        } else {
            System.out.println("\tYou Accepted the offer of Banker");
            System.out.printf("\tYour case contains $%.2f and the bankers offer is $%.2f\n",
                    myAmount, offer);
            System.out.printf("\tYou've won the offer of Banker: $%.2f", offer);
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
public class Play {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game dnd = new Game();
        dnd.startGame();
    }
}
```

.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Player {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Banker banker = new Banker();

    public boolean gamestatus() {
        System.out.print("\tAccept or Reject! [1]Accept [2]Reject: ");
        int temp = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        return temp != 1;
    }

    public int nUser() {
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("\n\tPlease Select Your Case!: ");
            int nUser = input.nextInt() - 1;
            if (nUser < 0 || nUser >= 26) {
                System.out.println("\tInvalid input Try again");
            } else {
                return nUser;
            }
        }
    }

    public int remove(int index, Briefcase[] briefCases) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("\tPlease remove " + index + " case/s: "); 
            int nChoice = input.nextInt() - 1;
            if (nChoice < 0 || nChoice >= briefCases.length || briefCases[nChoice].isRemoved()) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("\tInvalid Input please Try again\n");
            } else {
                System.out.println("\tI'm " + briefCases[nChoice].getModel()
                        + ". You just removed case # " + (nChoice+1));
                System.out.println("\t|" + nChoice + "| contains $"
                        + briefCases[nChoice].getAmount() + "\n");
                briefCases[nChoice].remove();
                return nChoice;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Model` is gone. `Briefcase` is more useful, especially you don't have to use null values to encode a removed briefcase. I changed the alignment of briefcase, so there is no more dummy value. Then I tried to simplify everything a little bit.

This is far from perfect, there is still room for improvements.

Comment: what more could I improve?

Comment: @Andrew Asmer: updated

Comment: what it's does this do? if (! cases[i].isRemoved()

Comment: and also, I just noticed that each while loop has this  while (true

I don't get that, and within that block of code it doesn't contain a boolean that retusn false :|

Comment: 1) a `Briefcase` holds a boolean `removed value (instead of setting it to `null`), and this expression just checks that this particular `Briefcase` isn't removed yet. 2) I just translated your code: The loop asks "forever" as long as it has no correct answer. You can leave a loop in 4 ways: By not fulfilling the loop condition, by throwing an exception, by using `break` and - as I did here - by calling `return`.

Comment: sooo if I call return, the loop will break? is that correct? and the "if (! cases[i].isRemoved())" means that if the value is still false,? it will continue? am I getting it?

Comment: and lastly !cases.isRemoved() means that !=not removed? am I right?  sorry I am kinda having this confusion having this case

Comment: A `return` will leave the method where ever you are (except in some crazy edge cases with `finally`). For the statement: You can really simply read it like English "if (! cases[i].isRemoved())" -> "if not briefcase is removed" -> "if the briefcase isn't removed, then..."

Comment: okay let me get this straight  the keyword return will break the while loop right ? and lastly can you provide me another example of the "if (! cases[i].isRemoved())" ? with simpler terms kinda getting confused because of that

Comment: and what does this meaning? this is kinda getting complexed XD while(true) what does that do? ._. there's no boolean conditon?

Comment: `while(true)` is a loop that runs forever, conceptually the same as `while(1==1)`. The keyword `return` leaves a method, where ever it stands (even in a loop in a loop in a loop...). The keyword that leaves the innermost loop is `break`. BTW: I have a lot of patience and have no problem to explain every detail, but why don't you try it out yourself for such easy cases? And the meaning of keywords is described here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/

Comment: One last thing why did you declare the amounts as final? why?

Comment: They don't change, and shouldn't change in this context. I found that I sometimes forget to initialize member variables in the constructor. If I make them `final` (when possible), this can't happen, as the compiler yells at me. Generally `final` documents your intentions, e.g. if someone thinks you might have forgotten a setter, it signals that you left it out intentionally.

Comment: and BTW at Landel can you use logical operators on object? specifically "!"

Comment: No, only on `boolean`s. But a dot binds closer than !, so if you see something like `! myList.isEmpty()`, it means `! (myList.isEmpty())`, so you first get a `boolean` value from the object, and then you apply ! on it.